Clean data from s3 before uploading to RDS database
I have a .DAT file on s3 which has some bad character in it which is causing aws_s3.table_import_from_s3 to fail when we try to import the file into RDS database.
Any suggestions on how to clean the .DAT file in s3 before I can call aws_s3.table_import_from_s3 method?
Since the file sizes might be upto GB's the goal is to modify it without reading into memory using lambda's and the process should be efficient if possible.
I am open to all suggestions.


What is the format of that file? Is it just a CSV file, or is it in a format that is specific to the database?

I have mentioned it in the description, it is a .DAT file (extension is of type DAT)

Yes, but what is a .DAT file? Is it just a CSV file with a different name, or is it something specific to the database engine you are using? I was going to recommend some ways you could read and modify the file, but it depends upon the actual file format.

I have uploaded an image of a sample .DAT file. I can't share the original exact file due to confidentiality I hope you can understand. .DAT file is like a csv file but is more of space delimited it seems from the example.

Your data file appears to be tab-separated data.
I would suggest:

Use an AWS Glue crawler to crawl the data file and create a table definition in the Glue Data Catalog. This creates a table definition that points to the data in S3. Nothing is 'loaded' into Glue or Athena.
Go to Amazon Athena and run queries on the new table to verify it was crawleed correctly
Develop a query that can exclude the bad data
Use UNLOAD - Amazon Athena to save the 'cleaned-up' data to S3
Read the cleaned-up data into Amazon Redshift

These steps do not require writing any code (aside from SQL queries) and do not require any resources to be launched. Amazon Athena is very low-cost and only charge based on the amount of data read from disk.
